# MySQL: Selecting unique values from col1 of a table and summing the values in their respective col2s

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of multiple clip ids e.g. 1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5 and in the second column, i have a duration in frames - each clip only has one duration - what query can i write to add up all the durations for each unique clip? It's been stumping me for a while

Currently `SELECT SUM(framecount) FROM myTbl` returns a really high clip duration (as many clips are being counted twice). e.g. I have 5 clips in my system, with a duration of 10,20,30,40,50 but each clip may appear in the list i'm talking about above 20 times each.

Thanks!

Comment: So if there is a duplicate, which duration should it pick? Better yet, why are there duplicates?

Comment: I guess anyone, he says they are equal

Comment: There are duplicates because it's a list of how they link to other items - each clip can be included in multiple 'clip bags' - for want of a better word.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use the GROUP BY function:

```
SELECT clip_id, sum(framecount) FROM myTbl GROUP BY clip_id
```

Comment: If not, there may be additional fields or information that's missing from your question.

Comment: I read the question different: he wants the sum of duration, but each clip counted once. So he should write the sum() of a UNIQUE subselect. Right?

Comment: @HC289 in this sample: clip - duration what is the result? 1 - 10, 2 - 20, 2 - 20,3 - 15. is it {45} or is it {10,20,15} or {10,40,15}

Comment: I guess HC289 is no longer interested in an answer, as the reply on my question remains in the dark..............

Comment: Wouldn't GROUP BY aggregate all the clip values when grouping in a SUM, hence returning me the same result?